# How to send $_POST values from form to image tag

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I send $_POST values from a form to an image tag? Image is created by another PHP file with post values.
Code example:

```
<form name="grafiks" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"     onsubmit="check()">

<select name="kolsk" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
                <option></option>
                <option <?php if(isset($_POST['kolsk']) &&     $_POST['kolsk'] == '1') echo 'selected="selected"' ?> value="1">1</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($_POST['kolsk']) &&     $_POST['kolsk'] == '2') echo 'selected="selected"' ?> value="2">2</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($_POST['kolsk']) &&     $_POST['kolsk'] == '3') echo 'selected="selected"' ?> value="3">3</option>

</select>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['kolsk'])){ 
$kolsk = $_POST['kolsk'];
}


echo '<img src = "myplot2.php" ?$kolsk >';
?>
```

Comment: I don't get it. You mean you want the POST variable `kolsk` to be in the `src` attribute for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your server-side code in the `<?php ?>` tags, just as you do earlier in the file.  Something like this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['kolsk'])){ 
    $kolsk = $_POST['kolsk'];
?>
    <img src="myplot2.php?<?php echo $kolsk ?>" />
<?php
  }
?>
```

It's not 100% clear if that `src` value is a valid URL for your needs.  If that's a query string parameter then you'd need a key to go with that value, perhaps something like:

```
<img src="myplot2.php?kolsk=<?php echo $kolsk ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks tahats work. Nowhere on internet cant find this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to set the image src dynamically or something else, but

```
<img src = "myplot<?php echo $_POST['kolsk'];?>.jpg" >
```

should produce myplot1.jpg, myplot2.jpg, myplot3.jpg   depending upon the user selection.